# Extending an ideal of a polynomial ring to a polynomial ring with more indeterminates. Is it a tensor product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, ideals

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field, let $S'=\mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m]$, and let $I'\subseteq S'$ be an ideal.

For some $n>m$, let $$S=\mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]\ \ \  (=\mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m]\otimes_\mathbb{k}\mathbb{k}[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]),$$ and let $$I=\langle I'\rangle_{S}$$ be the $S$-ideal generated by the same generators as $I'$. That is, if $$I'=\langle f_1,\dots,f_r\rangle$$ as an ideal in $S'$, then $$I=\{s_1f_1+\cdots +s_rf_r:s_i\in S\}.$$

My question is: Is it true that $$I \cong S\otimes_{S'}I'$$ as an $S$-module?

If so, any idea on how to prove it?

Very appreciative of any help on this question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this post, "ring" means "commutative ring", and "algebra" means "commutative algebra".

### New answer

The following observations answer the question.

**First observation.** Let $R$ be a ring, let $S$ be a subring, let $I$ be an ideal of $S$, let $b$ be the $S$-bilinear map $(r,x)\mapsto rx$ from $R\times I$ to $R$, let 
$$
\ell: R\ \underset{S}{\otimes}\ I\to R
$$ 
be the corresponding $R$-linear map. Then

> the image of $\ell$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by $I$.

This is clear. Let us denote this image by $RI$.

**Second observation.**  Recall that an $S$-module $M$ is **flat** if for any $S$-linear injection $\phi:N\to P$ the $S$-linear map 
$$
M\ \underset{S}{\otimes}\ \phi:M\ \underset{S}{\otimes}\ N\to M\ \underset{S}{\otimes}\ P
$$ 
is *injective*. Then

> a free module is flat.

This is almost obvious.

In the setting of the first observation, if $R$ is $S$-flat, then the natural morphism form $R\otimes_{S}I$ to $RI$ is an isomorphism.

**Third observation.**  Let $K$ be a ring and put 
$$
K[X]=K[x_1,\dots,x_r], 
$$ 
where the $x_i$ are indeterminates. Then

> $K[X]$ is free over $K$.

Again, this is straightforward.

**Fourth observation.**  In the above notation, set
$$
K[X,Y\ ]=K[x_1,\dots,x_r,y_1,\dots,y_s], 
$$ 
where the $y_j$ are indeterminates. Then

> $K[X,Y\ ]$ is free over $K[X]$.

This follows from the third observation.

### Old answer

Let me denote the ground field by $K$.

We have a natural surjection 
$$
K[x_1,\dots,x_n]\otimes_{K[x_1,\dots,x_m]}I'\to K[x_1,\dots,x_n]I'.
$$
Is it injective? The answer is yes. Here is the argument.

In view of standard properties of the tensor product, we have a canonical isomorphism of $K[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]$-modules 
$$
K[x_1,\dots,x_n]\otimes_{K[x_1,\dots,x_m]}I'\simeq 
K[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]\otimes_KI',
$$
and the natural morphism
$$
K[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]\otimes_KI'\to K[x_1,\dots,x_n]=
K[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]\otimes_KK[x_1,\dots,x_m]
$$
is clearly injective.

**EDIT.** More details: We have canonical isomorphisms 
$$
K[x_1,\dots,x_n]\otimes_{K[x_1,\dots,x_m]}I' 
$$
$$
\simeq\Big(K[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]\otimes_KK[x_1,\dots,x_m]\Big)\otimes_{K[x_1,\dots,x_m]}I'
$$
$$
\simeq K[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]\otimes_K\Big(K[x_1,\dots,x_m]\otimes_{K[x_1,\dots,x_m]}I'\Big)
$$
$$
\simeq K[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]\otimes_KI'.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it. If I understand your argument correctly, you stop where you stop because $$K[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]\otimes_K I'\cong K[x_1,\dots,x_n]I' \ \ (=\langle I'\rangle_S)$$ as an S-module? Is this more obvious than the original isomorphism question? I'm sorry, I'm not very good with these tensor products.

Comment: Dear @Bart: You're welcome. I'll try to answer your comment, but I'm very busy right now. I'll do it tomorrow at the latest. By the way, +1 for your nice question!

Comment: Dear @Bart: This is just to tell you that I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, this was very helpful. So let's see if I finally got it right: In order to show that $$R\oplus_SI\rightarrow RI$$ is injective, we're tensorising the exact sequence $$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow I$$ with the (in our case) flat $S$-module $R$ (over $S$), where the first $I$ is seen as an ideal of $S$, while the second (rightmost) $I$ is seen as a subset of $R$ and as an $S$-module?

Comment: Dear @Bart: You're welcome again. I'd say: $R$ being $S$-flat, by applying $$R\underset{S}{\otimes}\bullet$$ to the exact sequence $$0\to I\to S,$$ we get the exact sequence $$0\to R\underset{S}{\otimes}I\to R\underset{S}{\otimes}S=R.$$ Thus, the natural map $$R\underset{S}{\otimes}I\to R$$ is injective. Denoting its image by $RI$, we get $$R\underset{S}{\otimes}I\simeq RI.$$ Finally, we note that $RI$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by $I$.

Comment: There, I finally got it! This was most kind of you. Have a nice day!